# Dynamically change the RDS IOPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, provisioned-iops

The questing I'm about to ask is something I have in my mind since the beginning of the migration of a large postgres database on RDS, which occurred on January 15th, 2022.

One of the benefits of the cloud architecture is the "**pay-as-you-go**" thing. So, since the provisioned IOPS is one of the most significant option impacting the costs of the RDS system, why can't I dynamically reduce them with a sort of scheduler?

Our architecture has a wide correlation with the standard working time speaking about the load and the traffic; this means that during the night there's a very low impact on the disks and the IOPS are under 3000, same thing on the weekend, while during the day they ramp up to over 10k. I don't think we're the only ones with this kind of pattern and I don't know why I should keep the IOPS to 10k, with a huge cost, when I can reduce them by 3 times for half a month, with a significant reduction in the costs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect the people on Stack Overflow to do about this. My recommendation is that you figure out why your IOPS are so high. And as a hint, it's almost always worthwhile to increase your memory size.

Comment: This is exactly how RDS aurora works. Pay as you go iops.

Comment: Oh, actually what I'm trying to understand is if I'm missing something. Maybe changing the IOPS has a cost itself for example or maybe I'm completely wrong about the architecture. I'd like to know if I'm the only one facing this problem.

Comment: You can [change the provisioned IOPS setting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.StorageTypes.html#User_PIOPS.Increase) for a database. Read that doc carefully and try it out in a development environment before you decide to do it in prod, as it means that your database cannot be otherwise modified for 6 hours or "until storage optimization has completed." My experience with changing storage is that it takes a very long time -- on the order of a day or more.

Comment: But as I said in a comment earlier, figuring out an architecture to avoid high IOPS is a better solution. I recommend going to `dba.stackexchange.com` and describing your workload. Best is if you can figure out specific queries that are causing the problem. As I said earlier, giving your DB instance more RAM is often the best thing you can do. Or moving large queries onto read replicas.

Comment: And Aurora may be a solution, but the problem there is that you pay _by number of IOs_. So if you have a high IO workload, you will probably end up paying more.

Comment: Thanks everyone.

I didn't know about the fact that the Aurora instance is more flexible than the PostgreSQL instance itself. I think I'll keep this in mind and I'll think about a migration if possible.

Actually we already went for an optimization thanks to the performance insight clues. But still I find weird that only Aurora has this option to dinamically change the IOPS, letting you paying less money when the DB is unused.

At the moment, i mande a script with an EC2 instance that changes the IOPS with crontab during the week.